How to config gopls in launch.json instead of setting.json?
I want to pass modfile flag in gopls to resolve the correct versions:
  "gopls": {
    "build.buildFlags": ["-modfile=/var/folders/03/_jm4m9x93vvc2bnlpqggp40w0000gq/T/tmpA/go.mod"]
  },

my project A has a coresponding tmpA folder which has the correct go.mod for building, after I config below setting, the current go.mod could aware the correct lib version:
go.mod could hint me about the version when build
while this should be not located in setting.json which would apply to my all projects.
is there any way to allow different project can resolve to coresponding go.mod based on modfile tag separately?

did you try putting the setting in workspace settings.json? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings
